# Autolayout not working properly

Tags: ios-autolayout

I have UIView in separate .xib file and I make UICollectionView in it.

- To add collectionViewCell I made separate .xib file.

Now below collectionview I want to add UIView.but my problem is I set height of collectionview dynamically by using code.

But when I add this using autolayout constraint to add view below bottom of the collectionview but view will add on distance where It put on UI.

I want that first setup collectionview than view placed below it.

[Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug985.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug985.png)

[Below UIView constraint I have already set [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiOXp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiOXp.png)

Thanks
Nirav Zalavadia

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the UIView below the UICollectionView, place the UIView in the bottom of the screen.

Then, use a constraint from the bottom of the UICollection view to the top of the UIView.

Comment: Hi Alexander My hierarchy is 
UIView 
 - UIScrollView
 - UIView
  - UICollectionview (Here only i want to add UIView so below that uiview there are lot's thing need to add like collectionview and other elements)